# I don't understand this SyntaxError. Why /app/app/...? It happens on Heroku, works on rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

My app works fine on `rails server` but when I deploy it on Heroku I get [this SyntaxError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iS07E.jpg). The strangest thing is that I don't have any /app/app directory. Why is it twice?

You can check all the code [here](https://github.com/FernAlvarez/RequestApp).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `/app` root is something that heroku does (just interpret the first `/app` as the absolute path to your app). That's not the issue here, instead it's that you added a whitespace where no whitespace is allowed:

```
<%= form_tag (some, expression, here) do   # breaks
<%= form_tag(some, expression, here) do    # compiles
```

This shouldn't have worked on your machine in the first place (maybe previous Ruby versions accepted that Syntax, but Ruby 1.9 won't for sure).

Comment: Thank you! I can't try it know, but this should be the reason.